# How to disable TRIM on SSDs in Ubuntu

Tags: ssd

I have enabled TRIM by adding discard option in /etc/fstab but even after removing it the  effect is not going. How to disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 14.04 there is an automativ weekly trim. You can disable it with:
`sudo rm /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim`
But I wouldn't recommend totally disabling TRIM, this will slow your drive down with time.

Answer (score 0):

### To check the status of TRIM timer

```
sudo systemctl status fstrim.timer
```

You would get something like this:

```
● fstrim.timer - Discard unused blocks once a week
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Mon 2022-01-10 06:36:56 CET; 31min left
    Trigger: Mon 2022-01-17 00:00:00 CET; 6 days left
   Triggers: ● fstrim.service
       Docs: man:fstrim
```

---

### To disable the periodic TRIM (TRIM timer)

```
sudo systemctl disable fstrim.timer
```

### To manually invoke TRIM (on all mounted FS)

```
sudo fstrim --all
```

---

Further reading:

- [fstrim man page #1](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fstrim)
- [fstrim man page #2](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html)
- [Does SSD Trim actually increase the lifespan? (Quora)](https://www.quora.com/Does-SSD-Trim-actually-increase-the-lifespan)

Answer (score -1):

Disabling trim is very important for legacy servers that pre-date SATA.
SSD's can be fitted for power, reliability as well as some speed increase by means of an IDE to SATA bridge or converter. Or a DOM package plugged directly into the MB.

Some of these hang on TRIM. Random writes to the SSD are 3-4 times faster than UDMA so TRIM does not matter, it has time to write twice.

My approach is to comment out /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim (c. Utopic or Trusty LTS)

```
#!/bin/sh
# trim all mounted file systems which support it
# /sbin/fstrim --all || true
```

Of course this will also affect SATA SSD's on a PCI expansion card, but that's something else.