# How do I disable Trim so I may have a shot at recovering a doc on my SSD?

Tags: data-recovery, ssd, trim

I had a libre document that autosaved when my computer shut off unexpectedly. Later someone exited from it and hit don't save. I checked the backup folder located in .config/libreoffice/4/user/backup and it wasnt there.

How do I disable Trim so that I have a shot at recovering this?
Is there a chance that for some odd reason files deleted there wouldn't be wiped by Trim?
Even though Trim is done weekly, is the weekly wipe complete, or is there a chance it won't be wiped completely until the next week?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think trim is enabled by default
to enable it add the discard option in fstab to use the fstrim command

I just looked it up it seems to be default for only intel and samsung SSDs
on my system this is noted in /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
After reading /sbin/fstrim-all it works on more that just those 2 brands
Patriot, SanDisk, and OCZ also get it buy default

in 16.04 there is no longer a /sin/fstrim-all script so I cant be sure what brands it will trim, but trim is still called weekly

Related question:
[How to disable TRIM on SSDs in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490245/how-to-disable-trim-on-ssds-in-ubuntu)